# No option to save bundle-id of iOS app to "mobile" setting in linkedIn app

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

I am trying to implement share functionality in LinkedIn from iOS app,
I have gone through [LinkedIn SDK Doc](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk). I am stuck when **Configuring my Bundle ID with my LinkedIn app**

As they have mentioned in documentation, iOS setting in following image

[image]

> After creating app using [create app in linkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/new) link, *iOS setting* is not available for iOS in "Mobile" setting page. but as per linkedIn documentation option should be in "mobile" setting.

After creating app in linkedIn

[image]

I know this is silly but I saved my app `bundleID` in following OS setting to get **linkedIn application ID**, unfortunately didn't get. 
[image]

But I took it from URL(I am not sure whether that is correct or not) and Did the remaining settings and added code in project, but not working.

### I guess this is website issue

Then also, Is there any solution to save bundleID of my iOS app in linkedIn app to get application ID ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to linkedIn developer team. Finally they have added iOS setting in linkedIn app for integrating iOS application.

[image]

without saving iOS Bundle Identifiers and iOS URL Suffix Schemes in iOS setting, will get error while app build in xCode.

> Error Domain=LISDKAuthError Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LISDKAuthError error 5.)" UserInfo=0x17d61b00 {originalDomain=LISDKServerError, errorDescription=either bundle id or package name / hash are invalid, unknown, malformed,

Comment: This functionality is available now.

Answer (score -2):

Open Your linked app from linkedIn developer account. Then Navigate to Mobile Menu: Please check screenshot below

[image]

Please check if you have Application ID : <01234> whatever, used in your IOS app info.plist.

Also confirm if you have added right IOS Bundle Identifiers: by tapping on ADD Button, and if needed IOS URL Scheme Suffixes in LinkedIn App.

Tap on Update Button and then try Login with linkedin on app, it will work.

-Happy Coding.

Comment: @Tejinder, Appreciate your approach....When I asked this question Linked-In was not having option for "iOS Settings" in there website (you can see the second image in my question), after two or three days of this question, Linked-In team has added this option(you can see in it my answer).

Comment: I faced same issue, so gave detail to save time of any developer who will work on this. Not sure why getting negative votes, if this answer is not helpful?