# How to get application id for iOS application with Linkedin app?

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

For login with Linkedin in iOS application I have created an iOS application.For configuring it on Linkedin developer website there is no textfield to accept input as iOS bundle identifiers.How to get the application id for linkedin?

Comment: you can create your application in the linked in developer site and get your app ID from there

Comment: rmaddy:Thanks for replying.
On linkedin developer  website if I go to enter xcode bundle id in "mobile" section they showing android setting as package name and package hash but I want iOS bundle identifiers field.

Comment: @AvinashTribhuvan, problem is not to get application ID. Just go to your linkedIn application, you will get it from URL itself like https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/1234567/mobile

"1234567" is the application ID.
But the main problem is you can not save your iOS app bundleID in mobile setting, because there is no option to save for iOS application as they have mentioned in documentation. I mean there should be option for iOS setting like android setting in mobile setting[As per documentation]

Comment: rmaddy:Thank you very much. From your given link(linkedin.com/developer/apps/1234567/mobile) now it shows iOS setting.Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No option to save bundle-id of iOS app to "mobile" setting in linkedIn app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209347/no-option-to-save-bundle-id-of-ios-app-to-mobile-setting-in-linkedin-app)

Comment: @AvinashTribhuvan, I guess you got your solution but Marking an answer with a 'check mark' is expected StackOverflow behavior. If the provided answer does not meet your needs, then provide a comment to the answer.

Comment: @sujay:Thanks Sujay. I am new user to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have mentioned in comment "Just go to your linkedIn application, you will get it from URL itself like linkedin.com/developer/apps/1234567/mobile "1234567" is the application ID".

Finally they have added iOS setting in linkedIn app for integrating iOS application.
From "iOS setting" in **Mobile setting** you can copy your linkedIn application ID

[image]