# Error authenticating using LinkedIn iOS SDK

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

I have downloaded LinkedIn iOS SDK which includes two sample applications. However, when I try both applications I get this error:

> ERROR = Error Domain=LISDKAuthError Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LISDKAuthError error 5.)" UserInfo=0x174260840 {errorDescription=Unexpected Server Error, originalDomain=LISDKServerError, errorInfo=SERVER_ERROR}

Also, I have tried creating my own LinkedIn app by following this link [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk-auth) and the same error occurs when initialize a connection to LinkedIn using this method:

```
createSessionWithAuth:scope:state:showGoToAppStoreDialog: successBlock:errorBlock
```

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: I try on a device with iOS8.3 and it works. It seems the issue ties to iOS8.4.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and works for me after add the Bundle Identifier in the `iOS`.

Eg. `com.example.App`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This error will be coming if you haven't set your "Bundle identifier" and "URL scheme" properties in mobile settings of your app properly in your LinkedIn developer account.

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209347/no-option-to-save-bundle-id-of-ios-app-to-mobile-setting-in-linkedin-app)! which might help you sorting out your problem.

Comment: I have looked at the link prior to posting the question. I did set the Bundle Identifier and URL Scheme properties. It works on iPhone with iOS8.3 but in iPhone with iOS8.4 it throws SERVER_ERROR when coming back from from LinkedIn.

Comment: What URL Scheme to set?

Comment: @ChanchalRaj  its just li + ur app ID  ..if ur application ID is 12345 then it is li12345.

Answer (score 2):

Open Your linked app from linkedIn developer account. Then Navigate to Mobile Menu: Please check screenshot below[image]

Please check if you have Application ID : <01234> whatever, used in your IOS app info.plist.

Also confirm if you have added right IOS Bundle Identifiers: by tapping on ADD Button, and if needed IOS URL Scheme Suffixes in LinkedIn App.

Tap on Update Button and then try Login with linkedin on app, it will work.

-Happy Coding.