# Linkedin SDK with iOS - authentication failed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, oauth, linkedin-api

I'm trying to authenticate an user with Linkedin SDK, I've followed guide [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk) (official).

So, in my **info.plist** I have inserted my personal AppId, as explained.

Then I edited app settings at https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps//mobile inserting:

- iOS Bundle identifier (the same that I have on Xcode project)

So, I link an UIButton action to this part of code:

```
LISDKSessionManager.createSessionWithAuth(self.permissions, state: nil, showGoToAppStoreDialog: true, successBlock: { (state: String!) -> Void in
    print("Login \(state)"
 }, errorBlock: { (error: NSError!) -> Void in
    print("Login error: \(error)")
})
```

On click, Linkedin app it will open and after authentication it automatically turn back to application, throwing error:

> Login error: Error Domain=LISDKAuthError Code=5 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={errorDescription=the request scope is invalid, unknown,
>   malformed, originalDomain=LISDKServerError, errorInfo=invalid_scope}

What I'm missing?

I tried example app that are inside SDK and works, but I can't figure out the differences..

Are differences inside app settings? (at www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/)

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you are requesting the basic information from the linkdin as the new Linkdin apis only provide the basic information

Comment: https://github.com/mandeepsangwan21/LinkdinLoginDemo

This is a demo app for linkdin login

Comment: You're the man! I had   var permissions = [LISDK_CONTACT_INFO_PERMISSION, LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION, LISDK_FULL_PROFILE_PERMISSION] before, now with var permissions = [LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION, LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION] is working!

Comment: @user3494194, how can I can full_profile if I don't want the basic info only?

Comment: Well now Likndin only allows basic info

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have used right linkedin Application ID in your app info.plist file, also if you have added your app identifier in your linkedin app.
For detail check link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37960838/3467325