# valid iOS bundle ID rejected as invalid in mobile settings

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

I have tried to add a valid iOS bundle ID to mobile settings of my Linkedin App, but I got

> Your iOS bundle id is malformed.

error

I have created this App ID in Apple developer website so I am 100% sure it is valid.

The App ID is the following: **it.GoApp.184InnovationSummitEnterprise**

The issue seems to be with the number after last dot, but i repeat that it is perdectly fine to creat an app ID like this, and also Facebook Developers website accepts this kind of bundle ID's

Comment: see if this answer helps you http://stackoverflow.com/a/31284496/1612489

Comment: thanks but I have already seen that. I can succesfully add an App ID if I remove the number after the dot. the problem is that it.GoApp.184.... is a valid iOS bundle ID, while LinkedIn website claims that it is not.