# iOS Bundle Identifiers:Your iOS bundle id is malformed

Tags: ios, sdk, linkedin-api

I am getting

> Your iOS bundle id is malformed."

error even when my bundle id is right.. I suppose linkedin does not accept numeric in bundle id.. my ios bundle id is **com.10times**

[image]

Comment: Have you check this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209347/no-option-to-save-bundle-id-of-ios-app-to-mobile-setting-in-linkedin-app

Answer (score -1):

The bundle id needs to consist of a (reverse) domain name (more than one word) followed by the app name, for example:

```
com.10times.myapp
```

Comment: No, this is not a issue. I think, issue is some different.